# How to write the csv file using existing csv file values

Tags: javascript, java, r, csv

I have a Csv file which looks like

```
name   day     value
anji       1        10
anji       2         6
aru        1         8
aru        2         5
```

I want to get the output of my new csv file as

```
name   day1      day2
anji    10        6
aru      8        5
```

Comment: Java?? Javascript? R ?

Comment: So what's stopping you from writing some code to accomplish that? Choose a language you're comfortable with and write some code. If you then have a problem, create a new question and post the code you've written, and we might be able to help. For now, I'm voting to close as "too broad".

Comment: I am learning R nowadays. I am not getting how to add multiple columns to csv file

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spread` from `tidyr` or `reshape` from base R.

```
xy <- read.table(text = "name   day     value
anji       1        10
                 anji       2         6
                 aru        1         8
                 aru        2         5", header = TRUE)

library(tidyr)
out <- spread(data = xy, key = day, value = value)

# or 
out <- reshape(xy, idvar = "name", timevar = "day", direction = "wide")

  name  1 2
1 anji 10 6
2  aru  8 5

write.table(out, file = "myfile.csv", sep = ",",
            col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```